# how to export all checkledistbox items to Xml document in windows form application c#

Tags: c#, xml, checkedlistbox

Im not able to display all checked data in xml document only last 
       selected Checkedlistbox item is displayed in xml i wanted to 
     display all checked data in xml please help me in doing this..

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    namespace GetDetails
     {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
      {

      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();

      }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

     private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Create a new instance of FolderBrowserDialog.
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        // A new folder button will display in FolderBrowserDialog.
        folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        //Show FolderBrowserDialog
        DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            //Show selected folder path in textbox1.
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;
            //Browsing start from root folder.
            Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = 
               folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text).Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string file in 
                 System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        //Add file in ListBox.
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("No files Found 
               at location: { 0}", textBox1.Text));
                }
            }
            /* 
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if(fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
             {
               checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(fbd.SelectedPath);

               foreach(string file in files)
                 {
                  checkedListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
                }
            }*/

          }
      }

    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
     EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter("GetDetails.xml", 
        Encoding.Unicode);
        xwriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xwriter.WriteStartElement("XMLFILE");
        xwriter.WriteStartElement("file");
        xwriter.WriteString(textBox1.Text);
        xwriter.WriteEndElement();

            foreach (String item in checkedListBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                xwriter.WriteStartElement("SelectedItems");
                xwriter.WriteString(item);
                xwriter.WriteEndElement();

                /*  for (int i = 0; i < 
            checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count; i++)
                  {
                      //checkedListBox1.ClearSelected();

       checkedListBox1.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[i]);
                  }*/
            }
            xwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xwriter.WriteEndDocument();
            xwriter.Close();

        }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}


}
  only last selected Checkedlistbox item is displayed in xml i wanted to 
 display all checked data in xml please help me in doing this..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contains correct code, only change which is required is to use 
`checkedListBox1.CheckedItems` instead of `checkedListBox1.SelectedItems`

Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter("GetDetails.xml",  Encoding.Unicode);
    xwriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xwriter.WriteStartElement("XMLFILE");
    xwriter.WriteStartElement("file");
    xwriter.WriteString(textBox1.Text);
    xwriter.WriteEndElement();

    foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        xwriter.WriteStartElement("SelectedItems");
        xwriter.WriteString(item.ToString());
        xwriter.WriteEndElement();

    }
    xwriter.WriteEndElement();
    xwriter.WriteEndDocument();
    xwriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being quite simple. checkedListBox1.Item[i] is a string value, and an explicit convert allowed it to be loaded into a variable. The following code works:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str="";
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
          if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
        {
            str += (string)checkedListBox1.Items[i];

        }
    }
     MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

Now you got the items. You can write to XML File.

**For Writing into XML DOC**

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("GetDetails.xml", str);
```

For more information. Go to [Official Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: elements are poping up in message box but, only last selected item is exporting to xml

Comment: [Mounika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8489669/mounika) , I have updated my answer. Check it Now.

Comment: checked items are not displayed in xml document, only last selected item item is displaying, would u please suggest me in writing all checked items to xml doc.

Comment: I thought your main problem was, you are not getting all checklist items [Mounika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8489669/mounika) . In above, str is giving you all checkedListBix items right.? by MessageBox.Show

Comment: yes Im getting checked items, wanted to export all checkeditems to xml doc would u help me in this regard

Comment: [Mounika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8489669/mounika), Check my updated anwser

Comment: Its not displaying all checkedlist items now also, would u provide writing to xml more precisely